# SelectBox onChange() method

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onchange

What happens if I call below statement in javascript.

```
var dropDown = document.getElementById( dropDownId );
dropDown.selectedIndex = 2;
dropDown.onChange()
```

What is the significance of calling dropDown.onChange(). Sometimes this is giving error and not functioning properly.

thanks!

Comment: Nothing. JS Eventhandlers are lowercase so `onchange` and not `onChange`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onchange()` is an Event that is called when the value of the input/select changes. So you can assign a function to the Event which then handles it. e.g.;

```
dropDown.onchange = function(){
    alert("I have changed");
};
```

Read up on some of the documentation about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onchange

Comment: onchange is all lowercase

Comment: @mplungjan very true :)